Using the new css light-dark() values with hsl/rgb with alpha
Based on this article, I'm trying to use css's new light-dark(color1, color2) value in my site.
In the article, hex colors and color names are used, but my site currently uses hsl-values to allow me to add transparency to the same color values like this (inspired by tailwind css):
:root {
  --foreground: 0 0% 98%;
}

.div1 {
  color: hsl(var(--foreground));
}

.div2 {
  background: hsl(var(--foreground) / 0.25)
}

The new light-dark() syntax doesnt seem to support this unfortunately,
/* This doesn't work! */
:root {
  color-scheme: dark; /* or light, or light dark */
  --foreground: light-dark(222.2 47.4% 11.2%, 0 0% 98%);
}

.div1 {
  color: hsl(var(--foreground)); /* doesn't work */
}

.div2 {
  background: hsl(var(--foreground) / 0.25)  /* doesn't work either */
}

Does anyone know of a syntax that would work here? JSFiddle to experiment with

You have a syntax error, as the MDN documentation for light-dark() shows, you have to pass in two colours, passing in hsl values outside of the hsl function can't, and won't, work. Instead use: light-dark( hsl(222.2 47.4% 11.2%), hsl(0 0% 98%))

@DavidThomas; I appreciate your answer, but that is why the question focusses on how I can create this with a valid syntax, while keeping the option to add an alpha-value to the variable later on, like in the .div2 example.

Do it like below:


:root {
  color-scheme: dark; /* or light, or light dark */
  --foreground: light-dark(hsl(222.2 47.4% 11.2%), hs(0 0% 98%));
}

.div1 {
  color: var(--foreground); /* use the color as it is*/
}

.div2 {
  background: hsl(from var(--foreground) h s l / 25%)  /* add opacity using relative color syntax */
}




I didn't know about that syntax; it seems it is part of the Relative Colors spec. Unfortunately, it crashes the page if I use this syntax now, I even simplified the JSFiddle here to use hex-colors, but that still doesn't work.
